# Batch merge multiple text files from different folders

Tags: batch-file, text, merge

I searched this site but all the examples I found were when someone wanted to merge all the files into only 1 file.

I'm on Win 7 x64.

I have 2 folders with 250 text files in each and the filenames (of the text files) across both folders are the same.

Example:

```
Folder A:
file001.txt
file002.txt
file003.txt

Folder B:
file001.txt
file002.txt
file003.txt
```

The contents in all these files (and across folders), are different. The filenames themselves vary greatly, too (I just named them like above for example purposes).

Now I want to merge the files from Folder A into the files from folder B.

I want to do this:

```
Merge FolderA\file001.txt to FolderB\file001.txt
Merge FolderA\file002.txt to FolderB\file002.txt
etc.
```

So if file001.txt (Folder A) had 500 lines and file001.txt (Folder B) had 300 lines, after the merge file001.txt (Folder B) should have 800 lines.

Right now I'd have to open the file in Folder A, copy all, go to folder B, open the 2nd file, paste, save. For 250 files that's just too much.

**Does anybody know of a way to batch merge text files from different folders as explained above?**

I'd just love to select all 250 files in folder 1, copy them, paste into folder 2 and have them all merged to their counterparts...but I guess a solution like that doesn't exist. If you know of a program or batch command that does this, I'm all ears.

Comment: You might want to provide some information on what platform you are running (Windows, Linux, Mac...).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Edited OP, I'm on Win 7 x64.

Comment: Have you played around with Python at all? Its a simple language that makes doing stuff like that really easy. Use glob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For %%a in (Folder1\*.txt) do type "%%~a" >> "Folder2\%%~nxa"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and please forgive my newby-ness...but...where do I enter this? cmd.exe?

Comment: Ah right. Tried it and it totally works the way I hoped. Thank you so much, you ROCK!

Comment: @Endoro, can you please explain how the above line is working ?

Comment: The code takes a text file from Folder1 and writes it's content to a text file with the same name in Folder2.